# how ActiveAdmin works with existing controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, activeadmin

I'm finding it difficult to understand how ActiveAdmin(http://activeadmin.info/) works with existing controllers

I have the following  controllers

```
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb
```

and I was successfully able to implement ActiveAdmin UI over my views in the above controller. But my question is I have added the following before_filter in my controller

```
class StaticContentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :list_content_types

  def index
    @static_contents = StaticContent.all
  end

end
```

But this filter seems to be not executing, in fact I changed the code inside the index method to

```
@static_contents = abc StaticContent.all
```

As it should give and error because of  'abc' section, but surprisingly my app works with out an error. My guess is 'ActiveAdmin' reads controllers my its own, not the existing ones

this is my index action path

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/static_contents
```

and this is in development mode

Can someone help me on understanding how controllers works with ActiveAdmin or am I missing something here

Following are my configs

rails (3.0.0)
ruby 1.8.7
activeadmin (0.3.2)

thanks in advance

sameera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activeadmin controllers are not the same as your app's controllers, they are separate. The reason your code is not causing an exception from the activeadmin interface is because that code is never hit.  The [activeadmin controller documentation](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#modify_the_controller) specifies how to modify the default activeadmin actions.

Comment: Hi @Brett, thanks got my before filter working, Just to clarify, does that means, I need to add  my controller actions (If i add some custom code to controller methods) to 'ActiveAdmin.register' block, if I need to get them running, Its it quite not-DRY approach?.. thanks